# Import an excel column to a empty column in an existing list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel

Are there any efficient ways to import an Excel column to a empty column in an existing list in a SharePoint online site?

Currently I am using Ctrl + C > Ctrl + V but, since the values are too many, so even if I paste `500` values at a time, the site hangs up.

Ideally I would like to directly import the data rather than copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved your requirement by using power automate to directly import an excel column to a empty column in an existing list .

Here are steps：

1.Create an empty column with corresponding names in the list you want to import（During my testing it called excel value）.

2.Convert the data in excel into a table, and upload it to the sharepoint document library (the document library is called Documents during my test).
[image]

3.Create a flow as shown below.
[image]

Below are my test results: Automatically Import excel value to empty column in an existing list after running flow.

[image: After my search, you might be able to paste a few hundred lines by opening it in Internet Explorer. Good luck!]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import an Excel file to an existing SharePoint list and indeed copy & paste does not support large amounts of data.

The only solutions involve either developing/scripting or using a 3rd party software.

You might want to consider using [SharePoint List Synchronizer](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com). If you need it only once, there is a free trial that is fully functional. Disclaimer: this product is edited by SoftFluent, my employer.